# What happens when two developers are committing non-compatible changes to master?

Tags: git, gitlab

We both start from a commit in master. I push a change to master, then another dev pushes his change to master. Say we have different code in lines 1-10. I don't notice, then make a minor change somewhere else, commit that. The other dev does the same.

For the incompatible code on lines 1-10, is it just alternating? So say someone else is pulling from master. Do they get a different line 1-10 just based on whoever committed last? So now we need to properly merge at this point; are we merging his "master" and my "master"?

If so, why doesn't the commit history show these changes as alternating? In the history, even though the code is different, there is no indication that this is the case with the red/green highlighting.

*Note that this question is asking "what happens?", not "how do you avoid this problem?"*

Edit:
seeing that people think this can't happen. I don't know what did then. Neither of us branched, but yet this is what the history looked like

[image: pic of branching]

In commit `283ab9ef` I committed a change to master.

Other dev committed `c4e654fb` to master that didn’t have my new code in it

I committed `d29e2fad` to master that once again had those changes from `283ab9ef`, incompatible from his commit.

Later I merged them, resolving a conflict.
From our perspectives, we were both pushing into master.

Edit 2:

Based on what I'm seeing from the answers below, the question all boils down to **how did he push `c4e654` without getting a conflict error?**
`c4e654` has parent `a26bd4`, but he pushed to master without an error, which ignores the change I made in `283ab9`

Comment: Note, by the way, that if you or they run `git pull`, that means: *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, typically `git merge`, if needed to combine work.* So `git pull` automatically tries to combine things first (as in the merge example in my answer). Sometimes you might want to rebase instead, so you can set the second command to be `git rebase`. I prefer to do it manually and check whether merge , or rebase, or something else entirely, is more appropriate: Git won't know about anything else, and you must pick merge vs rebase in advance, before you know what happened!

Answer (score 2):

Commits have hash IDs.  (Run `git log` to see them.)  The hash ID is the true name of each commit, so it's easy to tell if you have any given commit: do you have that hash ID?  If so, you have that commit.  If not, you can get that commit from whatever Git repository showed you that hash ID.

When you, or anyone else, make a *new* commit, that new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  No other commit anywhere, by anyone, can ever use *that* hash ID.  That hash ID is now for *your* commit.  (In fact, if we knew in advance exactly what you were going to put in your commit—your name, email address, date and time stamps, log message, source snapshot, parent commit hash ID, etc.—we could have told you what the hash ID *would be*.  Of course we can never know in advance what *time* you'll make your commit, nor what log message you'll type in, etc.)

But, each commit also stores the raw hash ID of its immediate *parent* commit.  So you and this other dev start working.  Let's give you two names, to make this easier.  I'll call you "you" and him/her/they "them".  You make *your* commit; its parent is some big ugly hash ID, `a123456...` or whatever.  They make *their* commit; its parent is `a123456...` too.  You and they run `git push origin master`.

At this point, we should make a side note: inside each commit is a *full and complete snapshot of all files*.  Your snapshot has the full copy of the file, with whatever you did on those lines.  Their snapshot has the full copy of the file with whatever they did on those lines.  The parent commit, `a123456...`, has *its* full copy of whatever was in the file before.  That's not directly relevant to *this* question but it helps later when you think about the combining process.

Anyway, you and they both run `git push origin master`.  One of you "wins the race" because you cannot both call up the *third* Git at `origin` at the same time: that third Git will hold up the "phone call" until one of you is done.  Let's say you win the race.  You send your new commit—let's call it `b789abc...`—to the Git at `origin`, and it says *my parent commit is `a123456...`*.  The Git at `origin` has its `master` at `a123456` right now.  So the Git at `origin` sees that this just adds to its collection of commits: it puts commit `b789abc` into *its* collection, and sets *its* `master` to remember `b789abc`.

Now that your push is done, theirs starts for real.  They send *their* commit, with whatever its hash ID is, to the Git at `origin`.  Their commit says *my parent commit is `a123456`.*  The Git at origin says: *Whoa, wait, my `master` is `b789abc`, and if I take yours and put your hash ID in as my `master`, I'll totally **forget** commit `b789abc` and lose it forever!  So no, I will not take your commit!*

Whoever loses this push race sees their push `rejected` as a `non-fast-forward`.  The winner wins, and the loser of the race must do more work.

In this case, they—whoever they are—should use `git fetch` to obtain your commit, `b789abc...`, from the Git at `origin`.  (That Git now calls that particular commit its `master`.)  They will now have, in their repository, a sequence of commits that goes:

```
             c987654   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--a123456
            \
             b789abc   <-- origin/master
```

(assuming their commit is `c987654...`).

Now *they*—not the Git at `origin`—must *merge* your work and their work, which they can do any number of ways.  They have *their* snapshot of all files including their work, *your* snapshot of all files including your work, and the common starting point snapshot.  They must combine these three commits in some suitable way, to arrive at a *fourth* commit:

```
             c987654
            /       \
...--a123456         d888888   <-- master (HEAD)
            \       /
             b789abc   <-- origin/master
```

for instance, where this `d888888...` commit is a *merge*, or maybe:

```
             c987654   [abandoned]
            /
...--a123456         edcba98   <-- master (HEAD)
            \       /
             b789abc   <-- origin/master
```

where this `edcba98...` commit is from doing a *rebase* (copy-but-change-while-copying) of commit `c987654...`.

*Now* they can `git push` their new commit, whatever it is, to the Git at `origin`, because they will have *their* new commit remember, as its parent, the commit that's the tip commit of `master` in `origin`, so that their new commit just extends `origin`'s `master`.

Comment: heh, I was adding the commit hashes with an explanation to my question while you were typing this up... and I'm still not sure what happened. Niether of us got a conflict, niether of us merged, but if you look at master, the history has branched off at a point. My question ultimately distills to "why didn't the other dev see a conflict when he pushed commit `c4e654fb` to master?"

Comment: OK, studying the graph shows the fork. He must have made his commit on his `master` and just kept working. Later, he or someone else *has* to have done a merge, and whoever did the merge did it *wrong* by taking his copy of the file, instead of actually merging.

Answer (score 1):

The other developer cannot push to master till he pulls your changes first. At that point, if there are conflicting changes between your commit that is about to be pulled and his commit, git will raise a [merge conflict](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-merge-conflicts).

The other developer then has to fix the conflicts, commit, and then push. So the exact situation you describe cannot occur.

With reference to your third paragraph, resolving a conflict will indeed result in a new merge commit, that can be seen in the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.... git won't allow the second developer to push unless they force... so, under normal workflow, git will reject to push and will ask the developer to merge... when the developer merges, he/she will get a conflict that they will have to resolve in order to be able to push.

Any other person that start working from that branch will get whatever revision is at the tip of the branch when they last cloned or fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no PR's involved... git will reject the push the other dev makes. Git will force them to pull, at which point the merge conflicts will be realized and it will be up to the developer to fix those differences in code to determine what code to use for their push.